# Perfect scrollbar for text area is applied but scrollbar is not visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, perfect-scrollbar

My textarea will expands til a specific height, after that I want to show PerfectScrollbar. It was applied by functionality(Textarea is scrolling) but scrollbar is not visible(hidden).

I have added the below code in my textarea's keydown event.

```js
$(element).perfectScrollbar({
    minScrollbarLength: 40,
    maxScrollbarLength: 80
});
```

Comment: Have you added CSS?

Comment: No, I didn't added any specific css.

Comment: So add it to apply custom CSS

Comment: custom styles didn't work.